# Oracle JET: Knockout not updating variable

Tags: knockout.js, observable, knockout-3.0, oracle-jet

I have the following oracle jet and knockout html file

```
<oj-dialog style="display:none;width: 600px;" id="addNewTag" title='Tag New Build' cancel-behavior='icon'>
        <div slot="body">
            <div class="oj-form-layout">
                <div class="oj-form oj-sm-odd-cols-12 oj-md-odd-cols-4 oj-md-labels-inline oj-form-cols-labels-inline oj-form-cols-max2">
                    <div class="oj-flex">
                        <div class="oj-flex-item">
                            <oj-label for="releaseVersion">Release Version</oj-label>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="oj-flex-item">
                            <oj-input-text id="releaseVersion" data-bind="attr: {value: jobDetails().faReleaseVersion}"></oj-input-text>
                        </div>
```

I have following snippet of JS file

```
       self.addTagsToBuild = function (data) {
            self.jobDetails(data);
                $('#addNewTag').ojDialog('open');}
```

So basically I am calling function addTagsToBuild on click of a button which should open a dialog box and I want initial value of input text box to be jobDetails().faReleaseVersion which I have declared in data-bind attribute.Unfotunately when I am running this code jobDetails() is being passed as null and so the initial value of input text with id=releaseVersion is null.What could be the issue? Any pointers?

Comment: I can assure you that when I do console.log(self.jobDetails().faReLeaseVersion) in js file I get the value and it is not null.

Comment: Please don't add to your question via comments.  [Stack Overflow  is not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums).  Instead, simply click the edit button under your question to add any relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oj-input-text` is (obviously) an input field and so it both reads and writes to an observable you bind it to.

But your code is not binding it to an observable. In fact, you shouldn't even use `data-bind` for OJET components, because they are already used internally. You have to use the custom properties of each component.

---

First, you need to create a separate observable for `oj-input-text`. Why? Because if it is not on observable then no change event will be fired to the HTML to indicate that the value of `faReleaseVersion` has been updated.

```
self.faReleaseVersion = ko.observable();
self.addTagsToBuild = function (data) {
        self.jobDetails(data);
        self.faReleaseVersion(data.faReleaseVersion);
        $('#addNewTag').ojDialog('open');}
```

Next, use the `value` property of `oj-input-text` to bind it to `faReleaseVersion`.

```
<oj-input-text id="releaseVersion" value="{{faReleaseVersion}}"></oj-input-text>
```

---

Here's the [Cookbook](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=textInput&demo=text) link that shows how to use `oj-input-text`, and here's the [documentation](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.ojInputText.html).

Answer (score 0):

Bind your variable to an observable then knockout starts observing

```
self.testVariable = ko.observable();
```