# Why is observable not firing?

Tags: knockout.js, custom-component, knockout-3.0, oracle-jet

I have the following JS code

```
        self.tagBuild = {
            systemId : ko.observable(),
            releaseVersion : ko.observable(),
            subReleaseVersion : ko.observable(),
            templateSize : ko.observable(),
            rehydrationCode : ko.observable(),
            repoLocation : ko.observable(),
            templateLocation : ko.observable(),
            faIntegLabel : ko.observable(),
            rehydrationCode : ko.observable(),
            cdrmDBTemplate : ko.observable(),
            dbOperation :ko.observable()
        }
```

I am initializing the values using the code below

```
            self.tagBuild.systemId(self.jobDetails().system_id);
            self.tagBuild.releaseVersion(self.jobDetails().faReleaseVersion);
            self.tagBuild.templateSize(self.jobDetails().templateSize);
            self.tagBuild.rehydrationCode(self.jobDetails().repoLocation + "/ovm-tooling/oracle-ovmautomation-all.zip");
            self.tagBuild.repoLocation(self.jobDetails().repoLocation);
            self.tagBuild.templateLocation(self.jobDetails().templateLocation);
```

I use tagBuild for opening a dialogbox.
The issue is that when user changes the values in UI,the values in 
self.tagBuild.templateSize() or other observables do not change.
What could be the issue?

The html code is below which uses observable

```
        <div slot="body">
        <!-- ko with:tagBuild-->
            <div class="oj-form-layout">
                <div class="oj-form oj-sm-odd-cols-12 oj-md-odd-cols-4 oj-md-labels-inline oj-form-cols-labels-inline oj-form-cols-max2">
                        <div class="oj-flex">
                                <div class="oj-flex-item">
                                    <oj-label for="systemID" >System ID</oj-label>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="oj-flex-item">
                                    <oj-input-text id="releaseVersion" data-bind="attr: {value:systemId,readonly:true} " ></oj-input-text>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                    <div class="oj-flex">
                        <div class="oj-flex-item">
                            <oj-label for="releaseVersion" >Release Version</oj-label>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="oj-flex-item">
                            <oj-input-text id="releaseVersion" data-bind="attr: {value:releaseVersion}" ></oj-input-text>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="oj-flex">
                        <div class="oj-flex-item">
                            <oj-label for="subReleaseVersion">Sub Release Version</oj-label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="oj-flex-item">
                            <oj-input-text id="subReleaseVersion" data-bind="attr: {value:subReleaseVersion}"></oj-input-text>
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="oj-flex">
                        <div class="oj-flex-item">
                            <oj-label for="templateSize">Template Size</oj-label>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="oj-flex-item">
                            <oj-input-text id="templateSize" data-bind="attr: {value:templateSize}"></oj-input-text>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="oj-flex">
                            <div class="oj-flex-item">
                                <oj-label for="templateSize1">Template Size</oj-label>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="oj-flex-item">
                                <oj-input-text id="templateSize1" data-bind="attr: {value:templateSize}"></oj-input-text>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="oj-flex">
                        <div class="oj-flex-item">
                            <oj-label for="repoLocation">Repo Location</oj-label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="oj-flex-item">
                            <oj-input-text id="repoLocation" data-bind="attr: {value:repoLocation}"></oj-input-text>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="oj-flex">
                        <div class="oj-flex-item">
                            <oj-label for="templateLocation">Template Location</oj-label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="oj-flex-item">
                            <oj-input-text id="Config" data-bind="attr: {value:templateLocation}"></oj-input-text>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="oj-flex">
                            <div class="oj-flex-item">
                                <oj-label for="FAIntegLabel">FA Integ Label</oj-label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="oj-flex-item">
                                <oj-input-text id="FAIntegLabel" data-bind="attr: {value:faIntegLabel}"></oj-input-text>
                            </div>
                        </div>               
                    <div class="oj-flex">
                        <div class="oj-flex-item">
                            <oj-label for="rehydrationCode">Rehydration Code </oj-label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="oj-flex-item">
                            <oj-input-text id="rehydrationCode" data-bind="attr: {value:rehydrationCode}"></oj-input-text>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="oj-flex">
                            <div class="oj-flex-item">
                                <oj-label for="cdrmDBTemplate">CDRM DB Template </oj-label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="oj-flex-item">
                                <oj-input-text id="cdrmDBTemplate" data-bind="attr: {value:cdrmDBTemplate}"></oj-input-text>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                </div>
            </div>           
        <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div slot="footer">
            <oj-button id="okButton" class='oj-button-primary' data-bind="click: saveBuildTags">Submit</oj-button>
        </div>

</oj-dialog>
```

Comment: You are just passing data from the "jobDetails" observable when you are initializing probably. The values you are putting into your observables, are not observables them selves, so if "jobDetails" is updated, ur tagBuild won't be updated

Comment: It would depend on what your HTML looks like. Could you show that as well?

Comment: @Ray.Please find the code  above

Comment: @Joonas89 I am just setting initial value using jobdetails.The variables like self.tagBuild.releaseVersion still remain observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to the [previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263051/oracle-jet-knockout-not-updating-variable) I had helped you with. You have to correct the way you define the Oracle-JET components.

- Don't use `data-bind` for Oracle-JET components, they are already used internally. You have to use the properties of `oj-input-text` directly.
- Also take note of the double brackets {{}} and [[]]. They have special meaning in Oracle JET. The first creates read and write listeners for the observable inside it, while the second creates just a read listener. Your code is missing that. But the initial values work just fine because Knockout is able to help you out till that point.

Redo all your `oj-input-text` tags like this:

```
<oj-input-text id="releaseVersion" value="{{systemId}}" readonly></oj-input-text>
```

Note that `readonly` is also a property of `oj-input-text` tag, and so it will work nicely, providing the OJET styles to convert the input to readonly mode.

Here's the [Cookbook](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=textInput&demo=text) that shows you the right syntax for the tag, and here's the [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.ojInputText.html) that shows you every property you can possibly use for the tag.

---

P.S. Please think of the Cookbook as your bible for OJET. It's beautifully written and very thorough. You won't be able to use OJET components any other way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.You have mentioned that we should not use data-bind for oracle jet components but I see we have used data-bind frequently in our  application like follows

<oj-input-text id="filter" maxlength="30" placeholder="Type to filter" data-bind="event: {keyup: handleKeyUp},attr: {value: filter}">
                        </oj-input-text>
and it works fine

Comment: Interesting.. I would like to see that in working if possible. Because it looks like `filter` won't update in the JS.

Comment: Btw, could you help me out by upvoting the previous question's answer? thanks :)

Comment: Although I agree the event binding would work properly, because of the 'bubbling up' feature.

Comment: I have already upvoted your answer.Anything else you want me to do?

Comment: No no I meant the previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263051/oracle-jet-knockout-not-updating-variable

Comment: I can't upvote as I need to have some minimum number of posts before I can upvote as I am new to stackoverflow :)
I have one issue with the solution suggested.
As you suggested ,I have done as below
<div class="oj-flex-item">
                                <oj-input-text id="subReleaseVersion" value={{subReleaseVersion}} required='true'></oj-input-text>
                            </div>

Since required is true,it should give error if user does not give any value.But it does not show error.Any pointers?

Comment: Oh ok no problem :) I'm not sure why, but you can see a working sample here http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=validators&demo=requiredValidator